# Implementing a Subsystem Communication Design Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, facade

I am looking for an appropriate design pattern for the following:

I have the following system structure:

```
MainApplication
    SubSystem1
    SubSystem2
    SubSystem3
```

Where the MainApplication initializes each subsystem,

```
    SubSystem1 s1;
    SubSystem2 s2;
    SubSystem3 s3;

    public MainApplication()
    {
        s1 = new SubSystem1();
        s2 = new SubSystem2();
        s3 = new SubSystem3();
    }
```

and each subsystem should be able to communicate with one another.

Within each subsystem how can I call a method from another subsystem? For example in `s1`

```
    public SubSystem1()
    {
        s2.Method1();
        s3.Method2();
    }
```

Would a Facade Design Pattern work here? If so, how would it be implemented? If not which design pattern should be used for this scenario?

Comment: What is the extend of communication? Is it event based in nature or subsystem 1 does x and therefore subsystem 2 needs to also do y?

Comment: Currently, it is the latter. Although, using events sounds like a nice solution. Can you expand on this?

Comment: Well so if it would be event based like ohh music came over the wire. You could use events (built-in .net) to subscribe to the events and have each sub system process as necessary. This would prevent the subsystems from having to know about each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pretty much depends on the kind of communication between the subsystems.

If it is abstract, i.e. the subsystems do not actually have to know about each other, a **publish-subscribe based messaging mechanism** may be appropriate. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe for an introduction, but i think the concept should be fairly straight-forward.

If, on the other hand, the subsystems really have to know each other in a concrete way, why are they subsystems in the first place? Making this kind of partitioning indicates that there is indeed a separation of concerns, so finding an abstract interface should not be that hard. If it is, maybe you should reconsider your subsystem responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I never could remember design pattern names. Why can't you let each subsystem know the other subsystems?

```
s1.SetSubsystem2(s2);
s1.SetSubsystem3(s3); 
...
```

If you want to be more future-change-resilient, describe each subsystem's interface in an `interface`, and make sure SetSubsystemX takes that interface, and not the concrete class.

EDIT: An example of an interface.

Let's say your first subsystem knows how to send an email, and the second subsystem knows how to print a file. You should declare two interfaces:

```
interface IEmailSubsystem
{
    void SendEmail(string content);
}

interface IPrintSubsystem
{
    void PrintFile(string path);
}
```

Then you can define your two Subsystem objects:

```
class Subsystem1: IEmailSubsystem ...
class Subsystem2: IPrintSubsystem ...
```

If you ever going to end up needing more than the 3 subsystems, you should have a global subsystem registry, but don't worry about it just yet.

Comment: So from `MainApplication` we would send the subsystem objects to each subsystem? Interesting. I'm interested in using the interface you mentioned, can you expand your answer to show an example? Thanks.

Comment: If this is a good solution, a list that would add and remove subsystems of the interface would be better then holding n variables of subsystems.